# How to make opened menu transparent on scrolling up or down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently building my own website and it has been a while since I did anything with HTML/CSS, let alone JS. So I'm a beginner.

I have build a navbar that shows on scroll up and disappears on scroll down. However, I now have a simplistic solution for hiding the menu when it is open. I want the list items to disappear when the user scrolls - both up and down - and that is currently done by clicking the menu again (`if (checkbox.checked == true) {checkbox.click()`). The items move to their initial position of `margin-left: -57px`, outside of the screen. What I would like is the opened menu to become transparent, so the user won't see it slide out the window. The navbar itself can slide up and down, it is just the list items I'm talking about.

I have tried to add a class that has `opacity: 0;` to the menu when open in case of scrolling. However, after scrolling once, it remained transparent so opening the menu again wouldn't show anything. Is there a way to reset the transparency? Returning to the initial status everytime the user scrolls?

I appreciate any help. If my code looks off, please let me know!

```js
var previousScroll = window.pageYOffset;
var navbar = document.getElementById("nav");
var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox-hamburger");

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 60 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 76) {
    var currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
    if (previousScroll > currentScroll) {
      if (checkbox.checked == true) {
        checkbox.click();
        navbar.style.top = "0";
      }
      else {
      navbar.style.top = "0";
      }
    }
    else if (previousScroll < currentScroll) {
      if (checkbox.checked == true) {
        checkbox.click();
        navbar.style.top = "-70px";
      }
      else {
      navbar.style.top = "-70px";
      }
    }
    else {
      // Code for Chrome, Safari, Opera
      navbar.style.WebkitTransform = "none"; 
      // Code for IE9
      navbar.style.msTransform = "none"; 
      // Standard syntax
      navbar.style.transform = "none";
    }
  }
  previousScroll = currentScroll;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300vh; 
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -10px grey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar-menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0 20px 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#checkbox-hamburger {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  left: -12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#navbar-menu span {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  position: relative;
  background: #232323;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 2px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.3s ease;
}

#checkbox-hamburger:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(4) {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#checkbox-hamburger:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#checkbox-hamburger:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#checkbox-hamburger:checked ~ ul {
  transform: none;
}


#navbar-links {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: -57px;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#navbar-links li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  background: #fff;
}

#navbar-links li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#navbar-links a {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar-links a:hover {
  color: #cfb53b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="nav">
    <div id="navbar-menu">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-hamburger" />
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <ul id="navbar-links">
        <li><a href="#anchor-about">About</a></li>      
        <li><a href="#anchor-work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#anchor-contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Is there a way to reset the transparency?` add a class when it should be transparent, remove it when it shouldn't.

Comment: What about targeting the actual id="navbar-links"? So on scroll give it opacity, and on click return opacity. But on menu toggle open/close you dont worry about opacity so always just set it as opacity on.

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for. It's just that I don't know how to translate this into code. Can you help me get started?

Comment: @Sprep, thank you for your suggestion. I made a few changes based on your idea, and it helped. Not sure if it's what you meant, but it works for me. Let me see if I can post the new code down below.

Comment: @user12800122 yes that is what I meant. Looking at your example it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the idea of @Sprep I tried some new things and the code below works for me. I added `opacity: 0` to `#navbar-links` and when `checkbox-hamburger` is checked (open) I change the opacity of `#navbar-links` to 1. It only works with setting `max-height` though.

```js
var previousScroll = window.pageYOffset;
var navbar = document.getElementById("nav");
var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox-hamburger");

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 60 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 76) {
    var currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
    if (previousScroll > currentScroll) {
      if (checkbox.checked == true) {
        checkbox.click();
        navbar.style.top = "0";
      }
      else {
      navbar.style.top = "0";
      }
    }
    else if (previousScroll < currentScroll) {
      if (checkbox.checked == true) {
        checkbox.click();
        navbar.style.top = "-70px";
      }
      else {
      navbar.style.top = "-70px";
      }
    }
    else {
      // Code for Chrome, Safari, Opera
      navbar.style.WebkitTransform = "none"; 
      // Code for IE9
      navbar.style.msTransform = "none"; 
      // Standard syntax
      navbar.style.transform = "none";
    }
  }
  previousScroll = currentScroll;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300vh; 
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -10px grey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#navbar-menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0 20px 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#checkbox-hamburger {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  left: -12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#navbar-menu span {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  position: relative;
  background: #232323;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 2px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.3s ease;
}

#checkbox-hamburger:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(4) {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#checkbox-hamburger:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#checkbox-hamburger:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#checkbox-hamburger:checked ~ #navbar-links {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 999px; 
  transition: opacity 0.6s, max-height 0s;
}


#navbar-links {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: -57px;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  opacity: 0; 
  max-height: 999px; 
  transition: opacity 0.4s, max-height 0s; 
}

#navbar-links li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  background: #fff;
}

#navbar-links li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#navbar-links a {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar-links a:hover {
  color: #cfb53b;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="nav">
    <div id="navbar-menu">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-hamburger" />
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <ul id="navbar-links">
        <li><a href="#anchor-about">About</a></li>      
        <li><a href="#anchor-work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#anchor-contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```